# How to query so that a field of each instance will show up instead of the actual instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I am trying to query so that the value for a field in each model instance will show up with no duplicates. All of this is happening within the form:

```
class OrganisorClassStatusUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrganisorClassStatusUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['off_day_student'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset= Class.objects.filter(teacher=self.instance.teacher).filter(is_new_set=True).filter(time=self.instance.time).order_by('-date')[:10]
        )
```

Here, `self.instance` is referring to a `Class` model instance I am updating with this form. However, with this code, I would receive a list of `Class` instances for one of the form fields. What I want is a list of `Student` corresponding to each `Class` instances in the form field (there is only one student for each class). Therefore, instead of Class1, Class2, Class3, I would like to have Student1, Student2, Student3. Moreover, if there are any duplicates of a student's name, I would like to show only one. I hope the students are also listed in the order of `-date` for the classes as shown in the above code. Please ask me any questions. Thanks a lot.

Here is the Class Model as some of you have asked:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('Agent', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    student = models.ForeignKey('Lead', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='student')
```

Comment: You will need to build your queryset from the `Teacher` model, not the `Class` model, and filter according to whether they are associated with a class (and whatever other criteria you need).

Comment: Please share your models.

Comment: @michjnich Unfortunately, I used a foreign key in the `Class` model towards the `Teacher` model, which means that I cannot query for a class from the teacher's side.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added the model for `Class`. There is no field in `Teacher`(or 'Agent') that links it to `Class`.

Comment: You can link back to the class set from Teacher : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference

Comment: @codebuilder: what is `self.object` here? A `Use`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well... This is actually a simplified version of my original coding, since I thought it would take a lot of time to explain the original coding. Now... I think it owuld have been simpler if I just wrote the original code. But anyway, in this case, the self.object can be viewed as a model instance of `Class`.

Comment: @codebuilder: it is not really clear that if `self.object` is a `Class` why we need to first fetch the `student`, and then find all the classes of that student that are related to the student of *one* class. Perhaps besides the models, can you explain *what* you aim to achieve?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Would you mind if I just rewrite my whole question using the orignal code? Is that okay with you? I'm getting confused as well.

Comment: @codebuilder: yes. Please add all the relevant parts of the models involved and explain *what* you aim to do (not only *how* you want to implement this).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've finished editing my question. I hope you could take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with:

```
Teacher.objects.filter(
    class__student=self.instance.student,
    class__is_new_set=True,
    class__time=self.instance.time,
).order_by('-class__date').distinct()[:10]
```

If you define a relation from `Class` to `Teacher`, then Django adds a conceptual relation in reverse. You can specify the name of that relation with the [**`related_query_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) or the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). By default the `related_query_name` field is the name of the class in lowercase.

If you only want to retrieve each `Teacher` object a single time, you can not `.order_by('-class__date')`, since that will perform a `JOIN` for which there is no `GROUP BY` clause.

In that case you can for example order on the smallest `class__date`, for example with:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Teacher.objects.filter(
    class__student=self.instance.student,
    class__is_new_set=True,
    class__time=self.instance.time,
).alias(
    min_date=Min('class_date')
).order_by('-min_date').distinct()[:10]
```

or prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2):

```
from django.db.models import Min

Teacher.objects.filter(
    class__student=self.instance.student,
    class__is_new_set=True,
    class__time=self.instance.time,
).annotate(
    min_date=Min('class__date')
).order_by('-min_date').distinct()[:10]
```

or if you want the students:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Student.objects.filter(
    student__student=self.instance.student,
    student__is_new_set=True,
    student__time=self.instance.time,
).annotate(
    min_date=Min('student__date')
).order_by('-min_date').distinct()[:10]
```

The reason we use `student__` here is because the `related_name='student'` in your relation from `Class` to `Lead`. That makes not much sense however. It might be better to work with:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('Agent', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    student = models.ForeignKey('Lead', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='classes')
```

and then query with:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Student.objects.filter(
    classes__student=self.instance.student,
    classes__student__is_new_set=True,
    classes__student__time=self.instance.time,
).annotate(
    min_date=Min('classes__date')
).order_by('-min_date').distinct()[:10]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually edited your response so that i get a list of students(and not a list of teachers) like this `Lead.objects.filter(student__teacher=self.instance.teacher, student__is_new_set=True, student__time=self.instance.time,).order_by('-student__date').distinct()[:10]`. However, I still get several results of the same student in my form list. I don't know why this is happening, since the code includes the `distinct()`. Is there any way to go around this? I think this will be the end for this problem.

Comment: @codebuilder: that's because of the `-class_date`, if you only want teachers, you should drop the `.order_by('...')` clause, or replace it, for example with the minimum of the `class__date`sl

Comment: @codebuilder: then you work with `Student.objects`, and since the `related_name=...` from the `Class` to the student is named `student` (which makes not much sense), we query with `student__`, see edit.

Comment: @codebuilder: in that case it looks like you are querying for "classmates", not the teachers of the class.

Comment: Okay. I think it is working now. Thanks so far. But, why do I get an error when I submit the form that says `Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.`?

Comment: @codebuilder: because we take the first ten items, so with `[:10]`. If you want to paginate, you should use the pagination of the view, and thus omit the `[:10]`.

Comment: Okay, Thanks so much. I think it seems to work now. I haven't tested all of the possibilities using this code, and the entire code still doesn't work completely as I want it to work, but I think I might be able to fix it by changing some of the other parts of the website. But thank you for helping me out with this confusing part(well at least for me). I hope you have a nice day! Stay safe!

Answer (score 1):

If the teacher is a field in Class model you can say:

```
ids = Class.objects.filter(student=self.object.student).order_by('-date').values_list("teacher", flat=True).distinct()[:10] 
queryset = Teacher.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)
```

Here is the documentation for `Queryset.values()` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values
Please note: When using values() together with distinct(), be aware that ordering can affect the results. See the note in distinct() for details. (from documentation)
There seems to be a way to work that around. Please read the Note section in this documentation page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: I tried, but I received a weird list like {'teacher':1} for each class instance.

Comment: `ids = Class.objects.filter(student=self.object.student).order_by('-date').values_list("teacher", flat=True).distinct()[:10]`
`queryset = Teacher.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)`
This might not be the best option but might work. In the end, it does two queries. First one gets the PKs of teachers, second one queries teachers with those PKs.

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far, thanks. I don't know why, but it seems to work. However, my teacher list doesn't seem to be in order of the `-date` for the classes. Are there any way I could do this?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I read about it but forgot to mention. In the documentation there was a warning about ordering and distinct() clashing. I'll shortly edit my answer. Please take a look at that.

Comment: One thing to note is that I just completely editted my question as I had difficulty communicating with other users for this over simplified version of the actual code. The same logic is applied I think. I used your previous code's logic to mine, and it works as you said(except the ordering part). I just wanted to let you know that the question is now my actual code.